Google preadsheet GOOGLETRANSLATE uppercase results
I notice GOOGLETRANSLATE when used with capital letters gives wrong results.
Is there a way (using formulas) to make it ignore capital letters and translate everything as it were lowercase?
I am using this formula:
    =IF(B8="",,GOOGLETRANSLATE(B8,"en","hr"))

Samples:
"Lyrics" translated stays "Lyrics" while is should be "Tekstovi pjesama"
If I use lowercase lyrics, then its correct.

Can you put few sample and what you get wrong?

As per you modification example you need LOWER() function to convert all the characters to lowercase. Try-
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(LOWER(B8),"en","hr"))

For dynamic spill array try MAP() function like-
=MAP(TOCOL(B8:B,1),LAMBDA(x,GOOGLETRANSLATE(LOWER(x),"en","hr")))



If there a way for translate to bring back capital (if capital was there)? because now translation is lowercase but I still want same letter case as original.

Another issue with array spill formula is I have some blank rows, and it does not skip row but puts next row value where the blank should be.

@Toniq Then try =MAP(B8:B,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,GOOGLETRANSLATE(LOWER(x),"en","hr")))).

Convert cell value to lower case
Sample code
This will convert the value on cell B8 to lower case before translating it.
=IF(B8="",,GOOGLETRANSLATE(LOWER(B8),"en","hr"))

I have replicated the issue on my part so I can confirm your suspicion of the word "Lyrics" not being translated when the value being translated has an upper case letter.
Sample Output


If there a way for translate to bring back capital (if capital was there)? because now translation is lowercase but I still want same letter case as original.
